# Using web.config directory security and extensionless urls

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, web-config, authorization

I'd like to use the built in directory security features built into the web.config to restrict access to child pages of a parent page. My structure is as follows:

- Members
- Members/News
- Members/Press
- Members/Movies

Users should be able to have access to the members parent page, but not child pages. My problem is, because I am using extensionless URLs, the web.config thinks this is a directory and so access is blocked. Is there a way to say only restrict access for sub pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This configuration should do the trick. It is enabling anonymous access for the entire website, except for the additional locations - they need an authenticated user to work.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="Login" defaultUrl="Members" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>

    <location path="Members/News">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="Members/Press">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

    <location path="Members/Movies">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi. Whilst this works, I would like to be able to do it somehow by only defining it at the "Members" level (like how it works if you had a .aspx extension) as the sub pages are managed via CMS, so I can't quarantee what the sub pages would be.

Comment: I don't know if the <location> element support wildcards (have you tried <location path="Members/*"> to see how it behaves?).

If you need a wildcard authorization, maybe you can write your own HttpModule to take care of the authorization for you.

Take a look at this guy's implementation of his own basic CustomUrlAuthorizationModule: http://forums.asp.net/t/1346678.aspx

Comment: The location attribute doesn't support wildcards as this was one of the first things I tried. The CustomUrlAuthorizationModule might be a goer though. I'll look into it further. Thanks for you help.